# How to ignore files from the Java Build in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a `Java`/`Maven`/`Angular` Web project that includes a lot of static `node_modules` files.

Whenever I start VSCode it starts refreshing the workspace:

[image]

which takes a long time mainly because of the node_module folder.

I tried excluding it from VSCode by adding `**/node_modules/**` to VSCode settings, but it seems like the Java plugin doesn't care and still refreshes the whole `node_modules` folder.

Is there any way to exclude it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The default settings `java.project.resourceFilters` in the VSCode Java extension should have already excluded `node_modules` directory. No need to use `**` expression in `java.project.resourceFilters`.

```
    "java.project.resourceFilters": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git"
    ],
```

> Java > Project: Resource Filters
> Excludes files and folders from being refreshed by the Java Language
> Server, which can improve the overall performance. For example,
> ["node_modules",".git"] will exclude all files and folders named
> 'node_modules' or '.git'. Defaults to ["node_modules",".git"].

Comment: I used `"java.project.resourceFilters"` but it looks like it has no effect. I wanted to exclude certain folders from the compile process in a Maven-Based Java Project. When I try to lunch the debug process it fails because there are errors in the test package and they are not used. How I can exclude such folders?